# Minimize function using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How to minimize function y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + ... + y<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> with constraints y<sub>1</sub>*y<sub>2</sub>*...*y<sub>n</sub> = c; y<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,...,y<sub>n</sub> > 0 using dynamic programming? I have tried to solve this problem, but I have no idea how to create a recurrent function.

Comment: 1) Are c and all the y's integers? 2) For a given c, are you allowed to choose n?

Comment: @NayukiMinase 1) Yes, they are. 2) I'm not sure, but I think yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to think how to reduce the problem into "smaller problem"

```
D(i,c) = min { D(i-1, c/y) + y^2 | 1 <= y <= c }
```

In the above, you reduce the problem from `y1,y2,....,yi` to `y1,...,y_{i-1}`, and check all possible assignments for `y_i` - and chose the best out of them.

Base clauses will be:

```
D(0,0) = 0
D(i,0) = Infinity    i>0
```

You can do a top-down or bottom-up DP solution with these recurrence formulas, assuming `i,c` are integers. (Might need to add stop clause of `D(i,c) = Infinity if c is not natural`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and the clarification given, I think dynamic programming is not necessary. The minimal solution is to choose y<sub>1</sub>, ..., y<sub>n</sub> to be the prime factors of c (with repeats).

Example: Given c = 60, we let y<sub>1</sub> = 2, y<sub>2</sub> = 2, y<sub>3</sub> = 3, y<sub>4</sub> = 5.
Then the sum is y<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>3</sub><sup>2</sup> + y<sub>4</sub><sup>2</sup> = 4 + 4 + 9 + 25 = 42.

If we took fewer factors, then the sum would be bigger:

- y<sub>1</sub> = 60, then sum = 60<sup>2</sup> = 3600.
- y<sub>1</sub> = 5, y<sub>2</sub> = 6, then sum = 5<sup>2</sup> + 6<sup>2</sup> = 61.
- y<sub>1</sub> = 3, y<sub>2</sub> = 4, y<sub>2</sub> = 5, then sum = 3<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>2</sup> + 4<sup>5</sup> = 50.

Informal justification - it is always beneficial to split the product:
Suppose c = ab, with a and b ≥ 2.
Then c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup>. (a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup> > 2a<sup>2</sup>) and (a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup> > 2b<sup>2</sup>) are both true.
Adding these inequalities we get 2a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup> > 2a<sup>2</sup> + 2b<sup>2</sup>.
Therefore c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup>b<sup>2</sup> > a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup>.